# Store form data in local storage using array and retrieving it on new page

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the first page.

```html
<form id="myform">

  <label for="fname" class="fname_label">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" class="input1" placeholder="Full Name" name="fname">

  <label for="phone">Phone</label>
  <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">

  <label for="textarea" class="textarea_label">Address:</label>
  <textarea name="address" id="textarea" type="text"></textarea>

  <label for="select">Gender:</label>
  <select name="select" id="select">
                  <option value = "0">Select</option>
                  <option value = "1">Male</option>
                  <option value = "2">Female</option>
                  <option value = "3">Other</option>
               </select>
  <label for="select1">Category:</label>
  <select name="select1" id="select1">
                  <option value = "0">Select</option>
                  <option value = "1">Open</option>
                  <option value = "2">OBC</option>
                  <option value = "3">SC/ST</option>
                  <option value = "4">Other</option>
               </select>
  <label for="select2">State:</label>
  <select name="select2" id="select2">
                  <option value = "0">Select</option>
                  <option value = "1">Maharashtra</option>
                  <option value = "2">Gujarat</option>
                  <option value = "3">Rajasthan</option>
               </select>
  <label for="select3">District:</label>
  <select name="select3" id="select3">
                  <option value = "0">Select State</option>
                  <option value = "1">Select</option>
                  <option value = "1">Pune</option>
                  <option value = "1">Vidarbha</option>
                  <option value = "1">Thane</option>
                  <option value = "2">Select</option>
                  <option value = "2">Bharuch</option>
                  <option value = "2">Ahmedabad</option>
                  <option value = "2">Jamnagar</option>
                  <option value = "3">Select</option>
                  <option value = "3">Jaipur</option>
                  <option value = "3">Jodhpur</option>
                  <option value = "3">Bikaner</option>
               </select>
  <h id="qualifications">Qualifications:</h>
  <label for="checkbox1">BE</label>
  <input name="education[]" type="checkbox" value="BE" id="checkbox1">
  <label for="checkbox2">MCA</label>
  <input name="education[]" type="checkbox" value="MCA" id="checkbox2">
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="select-based-flipswitch">Subscription:</label>
    <select id="select-based-flipswitch" data-role="flipswitch">
                     <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
                     <option value="ON">ON</option>
                  </select>
  </div>
  <button id="myButton" type="submit" value="Submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my attempt to store value in local storage ,that user inputs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select').change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('select', $('#select option:selected').text());
  });

  $('#select1').change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('select1', $('#select1 option:selected').text());
  });

  $('#select2').change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('select2', $('#select2 option:selected').text());
  });

  $('#select3').change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('select3', $('#select3 option:selected').text());
  });

  $("button").click(function() {
    var name = $("#fname").val();
    var phonenum = $("#phone").val();
    var address = $("#textarea").val();
    var subscribe = $("#select-based-flipswitch").val();

    var qualification = '';
    var qualification1 = '';
    if ($("#checkbox1").is(":checked")) {
      qualification = $("#checkbox1").val();
    }
    if ($("#checkbox2").is(":checked")) {
      qualification1 = $("#checkbox2").val();
    }

    var input = [name, phonenum, address, select, select1, select2, select3, qualification, qualification1, subscribe];

    localStorage.setItem("input", JSON.stringify(input));
  });
});
```

This is the 2nd page where i want do display all the data.

```html
<body>


  <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-dismissible="false">

    <div data-role="header">
      <h2 class="ui-title">Confirmation</h2>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">


      <div id="content">
        <p> Name: <span id="display_fname" class="one"></span></p>
      </div>

      <p> Phone No.: <span id="display_phone" class="one"></span></p>

      <div id="content">
        <p> Address: <span id="display_textarea"></span></p>
      </div>

      <p> Gender: <span id="display_select" class="one"></span></p>

      <p> Category: <span id="display_select1" class="one"></span> </p>

      <p> State: <span id="display_select2 " class="one"></span></p>

      <p> District: <span id="display_select3" class="one"></span> </p>


      <p> Qualification: <span id="display_qualifications" class="one"></span> </p>

      <p> Subscription: <span id="display_select-based-flipswitch" class="one"></span> </p>


      <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b btn-1" onClick="window.location.replace('form1.html');">OK</a>

      <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b btn-2" onClick="window.location.replace('form1.html');"> Back</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

This is my attempt to get the value from local storage.Only Name, Phone Address are showing rest nothing is getting displayed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var storedInput = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("input"));

    $("#display_fname").html(storedInput[0]);
    $("#display_phone").html(storedInput[1]);
    $("#display_textarea").html(storedInput[2]);
    $("#display_select").html(storedInput[3]);
    $("#display_select1").html(storedInput[4]);
    $("#display_select2").html(storedInput[5]);
    $("#display_select3").html(storedInput[6]);
    $("#display_qualifications").html(storedInput[7] + " " + storedInput[8]);
    $("#display_select-based-flipswitch").html(storedInput[9]);

    localStorage.clear();
  }
});
```

Im only able to display name phone and address as output. Rest other fields are not showing anything.

Comment: You might be better off serialising the entire form, i.e `$('form').serialize()`, converting it to JSON and storing it in localStorage. When you access localStorage you only access a single JSON string and parse it, which makes things a lot easier. In that way, you don't have to manually map each input to its index in the array you are storing. Also, the root of your problem lies with the fact that the `.change()` event might not be fired on the `<select>` elements, so their values were never stored. And... `select`, `select1`, `select2`, and `select3` are never defined in your click handler.

Comment: Can you show me an example.

Comment: Can you show us your markup? It's helpful to have a minimal, concrete and verifiable example when asking a question.

Comment: I have added it. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a 1-to-1 mapping of your input element's `name` attribute to the span element's `id` attribute (i.e. `<input name="fname" />` maps to `<span id="display_fname">`, you can easily use a logic to do the following:

1. When the form is submitted, you create an array of objects containing the `name` of the input field and it's value. Convert this array to JSON and store it in localStorage.
2. When you choose to populate your DOM with the stored data, simply parse the stored JSON in localStorage, iterate through each element in the array. Each element will contain a pointer, stored in the `name` key, to the display element.

[A proof-of-concept is published on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/5ew1pfuc/11/) since StackOverflow's code snippet cannot handle localStorage without the browser complaining about CORS. However, the code below is quite simple:

**On your form page**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Instead of listening to button click, always listen to form submit event
  $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Create an array of objects called `formData`
    var formData = $(this).find(':input').map(function() {
      return {
        name: $(this).attr('name'),
        value: $(this).val()
      };
    }).get();

    // Store it in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(formData));
  });
});
```

**On your display/confirmation page**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Read and parse from localStorage
  var formData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formData'));

  // Iterate through array, and set HTML of matching <span> element
  $.each(formData, function(i, datum) {
    $('#display_' + datum.name).html(datum.value);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem("input", JSON.stringify($("#myform").serializeArray()));
  });

  $("#show").click(function(){
    var j = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("input"));
    $(j).each(function(k,v){
        $("#display_"+v.name).html(v.value);
    });
  });
});
</script>
<body>
<input type="button" id="show" value="show"/>
    <form id="myform">

          <label for="fname" class="fname_label">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" class="input1" placeholder="Full Name" name="fname">

          <label for="phone">Phone</label>
          <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">

          <label for="textarea" class="textarea_label">Address:</label>
          <textarea name="address" id="textarea" type="text"></textarea>

          <label for="select">Gender:</label>
          <select name="select" id="select">
                          <option value = "0">Select</option>
                          <option value = "1">Male</option>
                          <option value = "2">Female</option>
                          <option value = "3">Other</option>
                       </select>
          <label for="select1">Category:</label>
          <select name="select1" id="select1">
                          <option value = "0">Select</option>
                          <option value = "1">Open</option>
                          <option value = "2">OBC</option>
                          <option value = "3">SC/ST</option>
                          <option value = "4">Other</option>
                       </select>
          <label for="select2">State:</label>
          <select name="select2" id="select2">
                          <option value = "0">Select</option>
                          <option value = "1">Maharashtra</option>
                          <option value = "2">Gujarat</option>
                          <option value = "3">Rajasthan</option>
                       </select>
          <label for="select3">District:</label>
          <select name="select3" id="select3">
                          <option value = "0">Select State</option>
                          <option value = "1">Select</option>
                          <option value = "1">Pune</option>
                          <option value = "1">Vidarbha</option>
                          <option value = "1">Thane</option>
                          <option value = "2">Select</option>
                          <option value = "2">Bharuch</option>
                          <option value = "2">Ahmedabad</option>
                          <option value = "2">Jamnagar</option>
                          <option value = "3">Select</option>
                          <option value = "3">Jaipur</option>
                          <option value = "3">Jodhpur</option>
                          <option value = "3">Bikaner</option>
           </select>
          <h id="qualifications">Qualifications:</h>
          <label for="checkbox1">BE</label>
          <input name="education" type="checkbox" value="BE" id="checkbox1">
          <label for="checkbox2">MCA</label>
          <input name="education" type="checkbox" value="MCA" id="checkbox2">
          <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="select-based-flipswitch">Subscription:</label>
                <select id="select-based-flipswitch" data-role="flipswitch" name="select-based-flipswitch">
                     <option value="OFF">OFF</option>
                     <option value="ON">ON</option>
                  </select>
          </div>
      <button id="myButton" type="button" value="Submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b">Submit</button>
</form>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-dismissible="false">

    <div data-role="header">
      <h2 class="ui-title">Confirmation</h2>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">


      <div id="content">
        <p> Name: <span id="display_fname" class="one"></span></p>
      </div>

      <p> Phone No.: <span id="display_phone" class="one"></span></p>

      <div id="content">
        <p> Address: <span id="display_address"></span></p>
      </div>

      <p> Gender: <span id="display_select" class="one"></span></p>

      <p> Category: <span id="display_select1" class="one"></span> </p>

      <p> State: <span id="display_select2" class="one"></span></p>

      <p> District: <span id="display_select3" class="one"></span> </p>


      <p> Qualification: <span id="display_education" class="one"></span> </p>

      <p> Subscription: <span id="display_select-based-flipswitch" class="one"></span> </p>


      <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b btn-1" onClick="window.location.replace('form1.html');">OK</a>

      <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b btn-2" onClick="window.location.replace('form1.html');"> Back</a>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [openDB](https://github.com/pankajbisht/openDB) library to store entire object -

```
db.store.setJSON("key", value); //to set value
db.store.getJSON("key"); //to get value
```